# How to change currenturl with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 select option like 
 
`<select name="location" id="location">
<option>Dhaka</option>
<option>Khulna</option>
<option>Barisal</option>
<option>Sylet</option>`

 
`<select name="sublocation" id="sublocation">
<option>Mirpur</option>
<option>Uttra</option>
<option>Kalkini</option>
<option>Tungipara</option>`

 
`<select name="area" id="area">
<option>Dasar</option>
<option>Mirpur-1</option>
<option>Patgati</option>
<option>Nabagram</option>`

Now how to change the CurrentUrl with jQuery when the first option value is changed.
example: if my currentUrl is "http://example.com/home"
then if i change first option value i want my url like this = "http://example.com/home/first_option_value".

Comment: what you tried, post a fiddle....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call function on `onchange` and just pass the current select option.

**HTML**

```
<div>
<select name="location" id="location" onchange="ChangeUrl(1)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Dhaka">Dhaka</option>
    <option value="Khulna">Khulna</option>
    <option value="Barisal">Barisal</option>
    <option value="Sylet">Sylet</option>
</select>

<select name="sublocation" id="sublocation" onchange="ChangeUrl(2)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Mirpur">Mirpur</option>
    <option value="Uttra">Uttra</option>
    <option value="Kalkini">Kalkini</option>
    <option value="Tungipara">Tungipara</option>
</select>
<select name="area" id="area" onchange="ChangeUrl(3)">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Dasar">Dasar</option>
    <option value="Mirpur-1">Mirpur-1</option>
    <option value="Patgati">Patgati</option>
    <option value="Nabagram">Nabagram</option>
</select>
```

**Js**

```
  function ChangeUrl(value) {
    var FirstOptionVal = "";
    var SecondOptionVal = "";
    var ThirdOptionVal = "";
    if (value == 1) {
        FirstOptionVal = $("#location").val();
        if (FirstOptionVal == "") {
            alert("Please select Location!");
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "http://example.com/home/" + FirstOptionVal;
        }

    }
    else if (value == 2) {
        FirstOptionVal = $("#location").val();
        SecondOptionVal = $("#sublocation").val();
        if (FirstOptionVal == "" || FirstOptionVal == undefined) {
            alert("Please select Location!")
        }
        else if (SecondOptionVal == "" || SecondOptionVal == undefined) {
            alert("Please select Sublocation!")
        }
        else {
            window.location.href = "http://example.com/home/" + FirstOptionVal + "/" + SecondOptionVal;
        }
    }
    else if (value == 3) {
        FirstOptionVal = $("#location").val();
        SecondOptionVal = $("#sublocation").val();
        ThirdOptionVal = $("#area").val();
        if (FirstOptionVal == "" || FirstOptionVal == undefined) {
            alert("Please select Location!")
        }
        else if (SecondOptionVal == "" || SecondOptionVal == undefined) {
            alert("Please select Sublocation!")
        }
        else if (ThirdOptionVal == "" || ThirdOptionVal == undefined) {
            alert("Please select Area!")
        }
        else {

            window.location.href = "http://example.com/home/" + FirstOptionVal + "/" + SecondOptionVal + "/" + ThirdOptionVal;
        }
    }
    else {

    }

}
```

Comment: i already try this but i need like: when i change first option it work but if i change second option i need the url like this= ""http://example.com/home/first_val/second_val" ; how to do this?

Comment: No, its ok.. I am writing code for you.. will update my answer :-)

Comment: @KuntalGupta , check my post now. I have update it. I added checks for empty value so that URL should not be wrong. :-)

Comment: I am glad I could help :-)